# Define resource endpoint with member endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've got a model `foo`.

In my `config/routes.rb` I've got:

```
resources :foo do
  member do
    post 'approve'
    post 'delete'
  end

  get 'another_action'
end
```

If I do a jQuery `$.get("/foo/another_action")` call, I get the following output:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Foo with id=another_action):
  app/controllers/foo_controller.rb:20:in `show'
```

I have also tried doing:

```
resources :foo do
  member do
    post 'approve'
    post 'delete'
  end
end

resource :foo do
  get 'another_action'
end
```

How can I specify a route for `/foo/another_action` such that the controller treats it as a resource-level endpoint instead of as an `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
resources :foo do
  get 'another_action', :on => :collection
end
```

will generate the following route: `/foo/another_action`, while:

```
resources :foo do
  get 'another_action', :on => :member
end
```

will generate: /foo/:id/another_action.

Have a look at the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you! I had skimmed the routing guide but I managed to miss `collection`, and in all my Google searching I didn't think to use that keyword. I'll accept this answer as soon as SO will let me.